# Display objects from an array in order, depending on an specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this json:

```
var projects_array = [
{name:"proj1", category:"a", index:1},

{name:"proj2", category:"a", index:2},

{name:"proj3", category:"b", index:3},  

{name:"proj4", category:"c", index:4}
];
```

I am displaying them in order with something like this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i <proj_num; i++){ 
var numClass="p_"+projects_array[i].index;  
    var act="<li class='"+numClass+"'></li>";           
$('#lookfor').append(act);             
}
```

What i need now is to display first all the objects with the value "a" in the category attribute and then all the other objects in any order, i tried using .sort() in this way:\

```
 function compare(obj){
if(obj.category == "a"){ return 1;}                 
    else{return 0;}                     
}                       
obj.sort(compare);
```

But it does not worked because it kind of group all the objects of the category...

do you have any possible solution for this problem?

ps: I tried to simplify my code to make it understandable, i hope it be clear for you, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will sort according to the important word first.

http://jsbin.com/umezet/12/edit

```
     var projects_array = [
{
    name: "proj1",
    category: "action",
    index: 1
}, {
    name: "proj2",
    category: "time",
    index: 2
}, {
    name: "proj3",
    category: "buu",
    index: 3
}, {
    name: "proj3",
    category: "time",
    index: 3
}, {
    name: "proj4",
    category: "cooo",
    index: 4
}, {
    name: "proj3",
    category: "@",
    index: 3
}, {
    name: "proj1",
    category: "!",
    index: 1
}, {
    name: "proj2",
    category: "%",
    index: 2
}, {
    name: "proj3",
    category: "cooo",
    index: 3
}, {
    name: "proj4",
    category: "*",
    index: 4
}];
projects_array = projects_array.sort(

function (x, y)
{
    if(x['category'] == 'time') return -1;
    if(y['category'] == 'time') return 1;
    if(x['category'] > y['category']) return 1;
    if(x['category'] < y['category']) return -1;
    return 0;
});
for(var i = 0; i < projects_array.length; i++)
{
    $('body').append(projects_array[i]['category']);
}
```

Comment: thanks, what if the category value ais not just a letter but a word?

Comment: @lilymz let me think about that

Comment: look: http://jsbin.com/umezet/4/edit#source  , I used words and when i render it shows "time!%*actiontime@buucooocooo", and i watn it to render "timetime!%*action@buucooocooo" am i clear? :)

Comment: It renders again: time!%*actiontime@buucooocooo , both "time" should be at the beginig... OMG I'm lost!

Comment: @lilymz let me check. wait a while.

Comment: @lilymz glad to help. if an answer has helped you - you are welcome to select it.

Comment: hi again, I am wondering if you could help me again. I still can't figure out how to make my code work!!! The code you gave me yesterday works but i cant realize how to create my list, I was doing this
   for (var i = 0 ; i <proj_num; i++){ 
   var numClass="p_"+projects_array[i].index;  
    var act="<li class='"+numClass+"'></li>";           
    $('#lookfor').append(act);             
    }
it shoul dis